# Showing there is no such bounded linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $X = C[a,b]$ and $$M = \{f \in X : f^{'} \text{ is continuous on } [0,1] \}.$$ Then $M$ is a subspace of $X$. Define $F(f) = f^{'}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ for $f \in M$ (F a functional). Show that there is no bounded linear functional that agrees with $F$ on $M$.

My gut is saying to use Hahn-Banach, but I'm unsure of how to proceed. Could someone offer a hint to get me started?

Comment: I may just be misunderstanding the question. It's asking me to show that there is no $f \in M$ such that $f = F$ right? So I need to use Hahn-Banach to extend this hypothetical $f$ and get a contradiction, right?

Comment: Which norm are you using in $C[a,b]$?

Comment: Hint : consider the sequence $f_n(x)=\arctan(n(x-1/2))$. Are they bounded ? What is $F(f_n)$ ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The norm isn't given, but I assume it's the sup norm: $||f|| = sup_{0 \le t \le 1}|f(t)|$.

Comment: @user120527  So $F(f_{n}) = n$ we have that F isn't bounded, since M is a space of continuously differentiable functions we know that $f \in M$ is bounded for all $f \in M$, right? This would then be a contradiction. Have I followed your logic? I'm sorry for being slow, I appreciate your help

Comment: The point is to show that $F$ is not continuous with the norm given by $C[a,b]$, so there is no $C>0$ such that $|F(f)|\leq C\| f\|$.

Comment: Oh geez, I'm sorry for being dense. I understand now, thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's show that $F$ is not bounded on $M$.

Consider $f_n \in M$ defined as $f_n(x) = \sin\left(n(x-\frac12)\right), \forall x\in [0,1]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We have $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$ for large enough $n \in \mathbb{N}$ because $f_n\left(\frac12 + \frac{\pi}{2n}\right) = 1$ and $|f_n |\le 1$.

However, $f_n'(x) = n\cos\left(n(x-\frac12)\right)$ so $$F(f_n) = f_n'\left(\frac12\right) = n\cos 0  =n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \infty$$

We conclude that there cannot exist $C > 0$ such that $|F(f_n)| \le C\|f_n\|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $F$ is not bounded on $M$ so in particular it cannot be extended to a bounded functional on $C[a,b]$.